# Ionic build android in CLI does nothing

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, command-line-interface

I really tried to avoid having to ask this question but I've been stuck on this for a good two days. The problem is that when I try to run the command "`ionic build android`" I get nothing. No error response, no warning, nothing.

I installed node.js and made my npm global so I can access it anywhere. I installed ionic and cordova via npm install and I was able to start the application and see it on the web but when I try to run it on my device, I don't get any response at all.

What am I missing? I have all the android sdks as I normally write my android applications natively. I installed Ant view homebrew. I'm quite lost.

Comment: downgrade node to version 4

Comment: @jcesarmobile Well I'll be damned. That worked.

Comment: yeah, there are a few issues with npm 3 that comes with node 5. It's been fixed and will be released soon.

Comment: see here (how to downgrade as well):  http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-ios-does-nothing-and-just-drop-to-next-line/36067/9

Comment: cordova 5.4.0 has been released and it can be used with node 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there was a [bug in Node 5.0.0](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-build-ios-does-nothing-and-just-drop-to-next-line/36067) causing this.

I had the same issue as you, remedy, and was able to resolve it today by updating to the latest version of node (5.2.0 as of today):

```
sudo npm update -g
```

For some reason not (yet) known to me, the `cordova` command was no longer available after this update (returning "`/usr/local/bin/cordova: No such file or directory`"), but reinstalling cordova by calling

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

helped. After these two updates the `ionic build ...` and `cordova build ...` commands worked again.

So downgrading node to version 4 is apparently no longer necessary to resolve this.

Comment: Yup, it was answered in the comments although he never posted an answer, I'll accept this one because it was correct.

Comment: Yeah, thanks to hagai for the link! To split a hair, I also found the fact that the bug is fixed in Node 5.2.0 "new and noteworthy", especially since this means that downgrading node to version 4 is no longer necessary.