# npm an ionic not working installing

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to install npm and ionic but receive the following error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

> $ npm install npm WARN package.json infopharm@1.0.0 No repository
>   field. npm WARN package.json infopharm@1.0.0 N`enter code here`o
>   README data npm WARN package.json infopharm@1.0.0 No license field.
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "c:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe" "c:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" npm ERR! node v0.12.4
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
>
> npm ERR! error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line npm
>   ERR! npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601 npm
>   ERR! argv "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "c:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\ node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" npm ERR!
>   node v0.12.4 npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

Comment: The person in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33562353/ionic-build-android-in-cli-does-nothing) question needed to downgrade Node to version 4. He does seem to have it installed already though. When I used it (about a year ago) I also had a lot of problems installing everything needed for ionic. I `npm install`'ed and ran `npm update` a couple times till everything was suddenly ok.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to run the node command prompt as Administrator?